# Concatenar TextView Fijo con String proveniente de Hilo Android

Tags: android, hilos, textview

Tengo un layout donde tengo establecido un texto.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockValorAnoTop_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Maximo Anual:" />
```

Mi intención es que un valor que recojo vía petición web desde un hilo de la actividad, se concatene uno con otro.

Es decir: Si el valor fijo es "Máximo Anual: " y el valor que he recogido en el hilo es "55,6" se me adjunte a ese TextView.

Este es el código del hilo que hace la solicitud, ahora mismo lo saco en consola con un System.out.println pero. ¿Como adjunto esa variable con el valor fijo del TextView?

```
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {

                while (true) {
                    try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                        Stock stock = null;
                        try {
                            stock = YahooFinance.get("INTC");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        BigDecimal price = stock.getQuote().getPrice();

                        System.out.println(price);
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------");

                }
            catch(Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }

    }.start();
```

Comment: También puedes utilizar el método runOnUIThread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-to-use-runonuithread

Comment: m parece una solucion batante comoda la pondre en practica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías de hacerlo con un EventBus, el cual va a lanzar un evento y tu actividad suscrita va a recibirlo, pudiendo hacer lo que quieras con su valor. Los pasos a seguir:

En el archivo build.gradle del módulo agregamos la siguiente dependencia:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Ahora tendremos que realizar una clase POJO, es decir, una clase vacía con tan solo la información que necesitas, como esta:

```
public class MessageEvent {

    public final String message;

    public MessageEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Esa variable 'message' llevará consigo el valor, por lo que si no es un String deberas cambiar el tipo de dato.

Ahora tienes que declarar en la actividad estos 2 métodos, los cuales se suscribirán al evento y se "des-suscribirá" (para que nos entendamos..)

OJO: Si ya tienes el método onStart y el onStop en tu actividad obviamente copia solo lo de dentro.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Se registra en el bus por defecto.
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    // Se desregistra del bus por defecto.
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

De nuevo en la actividad, tendrás que copiar lo siguiente, que no es ni mas ni menos que lo que quieres realizar cuando 'salte' el evento:

Supongo que ya habrás obtenido en el método onCreate el FindViewById del elemento, de esta forma(y declarando la variable 'texto' a nivel de clase):

```
texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activityStockValorAnoTop_textView);
```

por lo que te quedaría así el resultado:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
    texto.setText("Maximo Anual: "+ event.message);
}
```

Por ultimo, solo te queda, en el hilo secundario, hacer el envío del evento y publicarlo, con esta simple sentencia:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent(variable_resultado));
```

Obviamente sustituye 'variable_resultado' por el valor del resultado obtenido en tu caso.

Comment: Me manda importar la libreria el android studio **add library 'espresso-core-2.2.2' to classpath** y al darle click no me la importa. Puede que tenga mal el gradel? te adjunto mi gradel al final del post

Comment: Cuando añades la dependencia en el gradle sale arriba una barra y tienes que darle a sync now. Mira esta imagen: http://installingcats.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/gradle-sync-now.png

Comment: Interesante eso del EventBus nunca lo he usado, yo lo solucionaría con un Future en la petición web

Comment: @Alvaro lo que no comprendo es cuando hago la llamada al método onMessageEvent(). El @ Subscribe hace que referencie al hilo del que recoge los datos, el que viene siendo el principal?

Comment: por cierto si solucione lo del grade ;D

Comment: Ajunto img http://es.tinypic.com/r/9azo8k/9

Comment: no he podido emplear tu método hasta ahora y funciona perfectamente, gracias ;D